# How to calculate minimum cycles of sine wave to have integer N cycles in a buffer?

Tags: audio, signal-processing, trigonometry

I found a similar question posted but not with a suitable answer.

I want to have sine wave buffers, doing audio synthesis, and wanting to figure an optimal size for buffers to avoid artifacts where the sine wave's period measured in samples is a non-integer.

For instance, a sine at A4, 440.0 Hz, with sample rate of 44100, repeats every 1/440 * 44100 samples, or every 100.22727272727272 samples. If you simply create a circular buffer of 100 (or 101) samples to contain a single cycle of the sine, playback has noticeable artifacts do to the disjoint.

Based on the response to the previous poster's version, the proposed solution was to express the period as a whole fraction and find the greatest common divisor to find the number of cycles and samples needed. However in practice I keep finding ratios where the greatest common divisor calculates as 1, which intuitively seems unlikely to me.

Using the above example, in Python:

```
freq = 440.0
rate = 44100
period = 1.0 / freq * rate 
ratio = period.as_integer_ratio()
from fractions import gcd
divisor = gcd(*ratio)
```

Divisor equals 1, apparently meaning that there is no common divisor, meaning that it requires infinite cycles of the frequency to ever find an integer number of samples to perfectly store the sine.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there another solution?

NOTE in practice, I've found that setting the buffer size somewhere around 1000x the actual period of the sine eliminates artifacts to the naked ear, but I would like to lower my memory usage and so would like to mathematically determine smaller allowable buffer sizes based on arbitrary frequencies.

Comment: Are you simply trying to avoid expensive calls to `sin`?  You may be thinking about this the wrong way, in that case.  You store a table of sin values, sampled at an appropriate frequency, and you then generate approximate values for `sin` at any value by interpolating adjacent values from the table.

Comment: paddy the buffer *is* a lookup table. im doing synthesis by adding many sine waves every frame to create harmonic overtone series, then doing this for every note played in a synth. copying buffers is much faster than calculating each sample on every pass

Comment: Sure, it's fast to copy, but then you can't easily have arbitrary frequencies.  Are you suggesting that you'll have different buffers for every harmonic that you want to add in?  It still sounds like you're thinking of this in the form of sample domain mapping to time domain, instead of the reverse.  It really isn't expensive to keep a "playhead" telling you exactly where in your wave period the current sample is, then look up the amplitude value in a table.

Comment: I believe that is very expensive. I've got an implementation storing effectively every diatonic frequency in audible range and only takes 2MB. All overtones can be pulled from this set with acceptable audible quality. I'm just looking at how to reduce the 2MB. Consider that playing a single note with 15 overtones is summing 16 numbers per sample. I would not want to additionally be looking up the value of each number. The sums are pretty fast and my buffers can likely be held in processor cache.

Answer (score 0):

What `gcd(*ratio)` returning 1 tells you is that the fraction you obtained with `period.as_integer_ratio()` has already been simplified, not that "it requires infinite cycles of the frequency to ever find an integer number of samples to perfectly store the sine".

However that simplification might not be so great given round-off errors when computing `period = 1.0 / freq * rate`. You would be better off using:

```
divisor = fractions.gcd(rate, freq)
ratio = (rate/divisor, freq/divisor)
```

At that point since `ratio` is a simplified fraction (in your specific case `(2205, 22)`), `ratio[1]` cycles would fit in an integer number of samples (more specifically `ratio[0]*ratio[1]` or in your specific case `48510` samples).

Comment: Ah you're right. I was too tired when I posted. However it does tell me the number of samples required to have integer N periods for many frequencies of interest is already much larger than my default case of just using 1000 cycles or so. 

I'm looking at an alternate approach of brute force checking for every N cycles how close to an integer n samples are required, and if the fractional component is below a threshold, using that. Not sure yet if this eliminates audible artifacts.

Comment: Incedentally though, the ratio returned by as_integer_ratio() is not very well simplified. E.g. print (440.0/44100).as_integer_ratio() shows (2875767925323201, 288230376151711744), which obviously is not as simple as (440/44100). And the fact that gcd() returns 1 on the ratio is evidence that either gcd() is flawed or the ratio obtained is off due to floating point error. I had better luck using gmpy.mpq().